# Django : Recreating all the tables for app in Django 1.9 version

Tags: django, django-1.9

I have tried using ./manage.py migrate app_name zero  command which was proposed but i keep on getting errors after i run python manage.py migrate testapp. My last solution would be to go to mysql drop entire db

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: testapp
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying testapp.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353,
_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345,
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", l
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 92, in
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 121, i
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 198, i
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 123,
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", li
rds
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 284,
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 110,
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in exec
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in exec
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\db\utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in exec
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.7-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 112, i
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'testapp_cinfo' already exists")
```

Comment: What's your problem exactly? Have you updated django and something stopped working?

Comment: yes, I updated the models of the app and i wanted to drop all tables for that app and recreate tables from updated models of the app

Comment: If you updated a model, you should first run `python manage.py makemigrations app_name`, which will generate a migration file for the changes to be made to the database and then run `python manage.py migrate app_name`.

Comment: i followed that but i still keep getting above error.                                                django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'testapp_cinfo' already exists").

Comment: Your migration file is running `Create Table testapp_cinfo` which already exists. Its your initial migration so your table shouldn't be there in the database, because your `testapp.0001_initial` will be creating it. Drop that table and everything will work fine (Unless there is another such table creation that already exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying an initial migration, which means that you are creating the first version of that app’s tables.

But you already have that table in the database so you can fake the initial migration

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

> The --fake-initial flag to migrate was added in Django 1.8. Previously, Django would always automatically fake-apply initial migrations if it detected that the tables exist.

But note that this only works given two things:

1. You have not changed your models since you made their tables (which you have).
2. You have not manually edited your database.

So you can't fake them either.

- I Want to use the current database

  If you have your previous unaltered version of initial migration files of the testapp with migration(non-initial) files with your changes, you can use them for migration.

  First fake that initial migration and then apply your changes
  (This may be tricky now, as you also have to truncate django_migrations table that stores migrations data)
- I can start from scratch -

  > No Problem (drop your database) as its an initial migration and that's what they are for - Create DB/Table.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have tables in your db, try `./manage.py flush` to clear all data. Flush carries out the SQL Drops on the entire db.

If you want to delete the db, drop the mysql db. Create another mysql db with the same name. Then run `./manage.py makemigrations` followed by `./manage.py migrate` to recreate the tables in the db.